# Get all the child details in a xml?

Tags: xml, linq, c#-3.0

I have an xml and i want to get the datas from it. I will pass a key Comp1/ and i should get the values and store it in dictionary. For example, in the XML, when i pass address i should return Housno, Street, City and Country as name value pair. If i pass Email, i should return Email as name value pair. I am trying to use LINQ to XML. I used to get the value of email using

```
resuls = (var res in xDoc.Descendant("Comp1/Email")
    select new
  {
      Name1 = res.Name,
      Values = res.Value,   
   }).ToDictionary<string,string>(a=>res.Name1,a=>Values);
```

If i pass address i am not getting the exact result. What i am doing wrong? I am also including you a sample xml

```
      <Companies>
    <Comp1>
      <Name>Comp1</Name>
      <Address>
        <HouseNo>3</HouseNo>
        <Street>Street</Street>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <Country>India</Country>
      </Address>
      <Email>test@test.com</Email>
    </Comp1>
    <Comp2>
      <Name>Comp2</Name>
      <Address>
        <HouseNo>1</HouseNo>
        <Street>Street1</Street>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <Country>India</Country>
      </Address>
      <Email>test@test1.com</Email>
    </Comp2>
  </Companies>
```

Thanks,
Jollyguy

[edit]

I have run your code and it works, but i wanted a common solution that will work if i add multiple nodes inside a node(Only First Level of childnodes) in future. i was able to do so using XMLDocument and i am trying to do the same using LINQ. Please find my code below

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictValus = new Dictionary<string, string>();
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("d:\\test.xml");
string companyname = "Comp1";
string findname = "Email";
XmlNodeList xmlList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Companies/" + companyname +"/" + findname);

foreach (XmlNode node in xmlList)
{
    if (node.FirstChild.Name.ToString() != node.LastChild.Name.ToString())
    {
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            dictValus.Add(childNode.LocalName, childNode.InnerText);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dictValus.Add(node.LocalName, node.InnerText);
    }
}
```

[/edit]

Comment: when You pass `address`, what result do you want to  return? how  Housno, Street, City and Country as name value pair

Comment: @Time.Tang. yes. the result i expect when i pass the company name and then the node name for eg.. Comp1/Address. i want the store HouseNo, street, city and country as name value pair. The result should be

HouseNo 3
Street Street1
City Delhi
Country India

Answer (score 0):

hope this can help：

```
void Main()
{
    var xml=XDocument.Load("d:\\test.xml");
    string key="Email";
    var list=xml.Descendants("Companies").Elements() 
                .Select(x=>new
                        {
                            Name=x.Element("Name"),
                            Email=x.Element("Email"),
                            Address=x.Element("Address")
                        });
    var result=new Dictionary<string,string>();
    switch(key)
    {
       case "Email":
             result=list.Select(x=>new{Key=x.Name.Value+"/"+x.Email.Name,Value=x.Email.Value})
                           .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);

        break;
        case "Address":
             result=list.Select(x=>new{Key=x.Name.Value+"/"+x.Address.Name,Value=string.Join(",",x.Address.Elements().Select(a=>a.Value).ToArray())})
                           .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);


         break; 
    }

    result.Dump();
}
```